# Best pratice to avoid selecting all rows when adding to owning side collection of a @ManyToMany

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

When adding to a collection representing the owning side of a @ManyToMany association, my JPA implementation (Hibernate) will first select all rows from the association to determine wether the entity is already present in the collection.

I understand the mechanics behind this, but when dealing with large join tables this is not very performant. What would be the best practice to avoid loading all the elements of the join table when I know I need to insert an entry?

I will exemplify with a classic User/Role scenario, getters/setters/initializers left out for brevity:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Role> roles;
}

@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

I let User be the owning side, so that JPA will track changes to user.roles.

The following code causes the issue:

```
User user = em.find(User.class, 1L);
Role role = em.find(Role.class, 1L);

// This line causes the issue
user.getRoles().add(role);

em.persist(user);
```

When I add to user.roles, the following SELECT is performed:

```
select
     roles0_.users_id as users_id1_20_0_,
     roles0_.roles_id as roles_id2_21_0_,
     role1_.id as id1_17_1_,
     role1_.name as name2_17_1_ 
from User_Role roles0_ 
inner join Role role1_ on roles0_.roles_id=role1_.id 
where roles0_.users_id=?
```

This is fine for small collections, but problematic for larger collections.

I can think of the following solutions, and I'm wondering which one I should go for, or if there is a better way of doing this?

### 1. Perform a native query:

```
INSERT INTO User_Role (users_id, roles_id) VALUES (1, 1)
```

### 2. Create an Entity for the join table:

```
@Entity
IdClass(UserRole.PK)
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    private User user;
    @Id
    private Role role;

    public static class PK {
        private User user;
        private Role role;
    }
}
```

Then I can run:

```
User user = em.find(User.class, 1L);
Role role = em.find(Role.class, 1L);
UserRole userRole = new UserRole(user, role);
em.persist(userRole);
```

I'm leaning towards using a native query for the insert, but I would love to get some feedback as to what is the most 'JPA' way of doing this.

Comment: Your both solutions have at least one disadvantage. Just look at it in the context of 2nd level cache or current persistence context. You would have to be really careful to not to fall into bugs. I will track this post, it is really interesting question.

Comment: Thanks @zxcf - I didn't think about the persistence context/2nd level cache, but obviously that would need to be adressed. With that in mind, a better solution is absolutely required to avoid bugs and unnecessary plumbing like cache eviction etc.

Answer (score 1):

The java persistence with hibernate book says (on page 298) that many to many is often best done with an association class (sort of like what you have already in your second solution, with UserRole) and then mapping two one-to-many relationships for either side--i.e. each user has many UserRoles, and each role has many UserRoles.  That is the most "JPA" way of doing things, and I think will get the performance you want.

Now for the subtleties:

1. The association class should have a composite key based on the ids of the Users and Roles, not its own PK.  The book gives an example of creating, inside the association class, an @Embeddable static inner class that holds the ids of the two primary classes (in your case, user and role).  The mapping of these ids to columns in the association table is done in this inner class.
2. In the constructor of the association class, to which you pass a specific role and user, you would populate the inner class, and then add "this" (i.e. the association instance you are creating) to the sets of both the user and role being passed in (e.g. role.getUserRoles().add(this).
3. When you delete an association, you must remove the association from both the user and role.  i.e. on the role side, you would do this:  role.getUserRoles().remove(userRole) and then you would do the same on the user side, and then you would delete the association:  session.delete(userRole).

If you follow these steps, hibernate will know everything that is going on, and your caches should be good.  You can also enable transitive persistence with cascading.

Edit:  As pointed out, this doesn't actually eliminate the query that was trying to be avoided.  After further reflection, I don't have an answer that will eliminate the query, but I can point out why JPA is behaving in the manner that you see.  In the original setup, each item has a *Set* of the other things.  As sets are unique, and JPA providers follow the collections semantics, they must ensure that the relations are unique.  Therefore, if you add a relation, it must query to make sure that relation doesn't already exist.  It could query for just the relation that you are trying to add, or it could query for the entire set, and then check inside.  The latter is a better approach if you are adding multiple things to the set, and that is what they have optimized for.  The one thing JPA providers would never do is rely on an underlying database constraint to be hit if you try to add a duplicate relation--JPA providers prefer to handle Java constraints at the Java layer

Hibernate also supports a bag option, which allows for duplicates, and so might avoid the check...but then, your database would have duplicate relations in it.

Comment: Thanks @DavidInTx - When I first read your post I though "This is it!", but then I started thinking - wouldn't the fact that I need to do role.getUserRoles().remove(userRole) etc cause Hibernate to load all the associations, just as with my original predicament?