# How to avoid unnecessary queries when adding an entry to a ManyToMany collection in JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have the following two entities linked by a ManyToMany relationship

```kotlin
data class GroupEntity(
    @Id
    val id: String,
    val name: String
) {
    @ManyToMany
    val users: MutableSet<UserEntity> = HashSet()
}

@Entity
data class UserEntity(
    @Id
    val id: UUID,
    val name: String,

    @ElementCollection
    val interests: Set<InterestEmbeddable> = HashSet(),

    @ElementCollection
    val badges: Set<BadgeEmbeddable> = HashSet()
) {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    val groups: MutableSet<GroupEntity> = HashSet()
}
```

Each of those entities have a corresponding `JpaRepository`.
Whenever I try to add a `user` to a `group`, then behind the scenes hibernate does many queries to the database. It actually loads every `interests` and `badges` from every `user` of the `group` I'm trying to add my `user` to.

```java
var group = this.groupRepository.getById(groupId);
var user = this.userRepository.getById(userId);

group.getUsers().add(user);
```

```
Hibernate: select badges0_.user_entity_id as user_en1_46_0_, badges0_.badge_id as badge_2_46_0_ from user_entity_badges badges0_ where badges0_.user_entity_id=?
Hibernate: select interests0_.user_entity_id as user_en1_47_0_, interests0_.name as name2_47_0_, interests0_.value as value3_47_0_ from user_entity_interests interests0_ where interests0_.user_entity_id=?
Hibernate: select badges0_.user_entity_id as user_en1_46_0_, badges0_.badge_id as badge_2_46_0_ from user_entity_badges badges0_ where badges0_.user_entity_id=?
Hibernate: select interests0_.user_entity_id as user_en1_47_0_, interests0_.name as name2_47_0_, interests0_.value as value3_47_0_ from user_entity_interests interests0_ where interests0_.user_entity_id=?
Hibernate: select badges0_.user_entity_id as user_en1_46_0_, badges0_.badge_id as badge_2_46_0_ from user_entity_badges badges0_ where badges0_.user_entity_id=?
Hibernate: select interests0_.user_entity_id as user_en1_47_0_, interests0_.name as name2_47_0_, interests0_.value as value3_47_0_ from user_entity_interests interests0_ where interests0_.user_entity_id=?
Hibernate: select badges0_.user_entity_id as user_en1_46_0_, badges0_.badge_id as badge_2_46_0_ from user_entity_badges badges0_ where badges0_.user_entity_id=?
Hibernate: select interests0_.user_entity_id as user_en1_47_0_, interests0_.name as name2_47_0_, interests0_.value as value3_47_0_ from user_entity_interests interests0_ where interests0_.user_entity_id=?
Hibernate: select badges0_.user_entity_id as user_en1_46_0_, badges0_.badge_id as badge_2_46_0_ from user_entity_badges badges0_ where badges0_.user_entity_id=?
Hibernate: select interests0_.user_entity_id as user_en1_47_0_, interests0_.name as name2_47_0_, interests0_.value as value3_47_0_ from user_entity_interests interests0_ where interests0_.user_entity_id=?
Hibernate: select badges0_.user_entity_id as user_en1_46_0_, badges0_.badge_id as badge_2_46_0_ from user_entity_badges badges0_ where badges0_.user_entity_id=?
Hibernate: select interests0_.user_entity_id as user_en1_47_0_, interests0_.name as name2_47_0_, interests0_.value as value3_47_0_ from user_entity_interests interests0_ where interests0_.user_entity_id=?
Hibernate: select badges0_.user_entity_id as user_en1_46_0_, badges0_.badge_id as badge_2_46_0_ from user_entity_badges badges0_ where badges0_.user_entity_id=?
Hibernate: select interests0_.user_entity_id as user_en1_47_0_, interests0_.name as name2_47_0_, interests0_.value as value3_47_0_ from user_entity_interests interests0_ where interests0_.user_entity_id=?
Hibernate: select badges0_.user_entity_id as user_en1_46_0_, badges0_.badge_id as badge_2_46_0_ from user_entity_badges badges0_ where badges0_.user_entity_id=?
```

As you can imagine this is causing me performance issues. I'm having the same issue when trying to remove a user by the way.

How can I avoid those extra queries ?

I've been reading through [Best pratice to avoid selecting all rows when adding to owning side collection of a @ManyToMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005315/best-pratice-to-avoid-selecting-all-rows-when-adding-to-owning-side-collection-o) but I'm not really satisfied with the answer provided there. I would like to avoid having to materialize the join table as an entity if possible.

Comment: I would not expect that to happen. Firstly can you clarify if you have any implementation of equals or hashcode - via lombok or otherwise - that may referecne all fields?

Comment: I'm using Kotlin data classes so I'm using the equals / hashcode provided by that. It means the groups nd users mutable sets are not taken into account as they are declared in the body.

Comment: @AlanHay OK, I think I got it from your answer. The fact my 2 other collections were part of the equals / hashcode made hibernate load the collections. By moving those out of the equals/hashcode I'm not getting the multiple queries anymore.

Answer (score 0):

@AlanHay's comment directed me towards the solution: I had my `interests` and `badges` collections as part of my equals / hashcode and so when doing this it triggered the loading of all elements.